# javascript assign value to global variable in function not working

Tags: javascript

I am using a global variable in a function but it seems I can't set it to a certain value.

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    var options = new Object();
                getdata = function(){
            return $.get('data.php', <?php echo ($params1); ?>, function(tsv) {
            var lines = [];
                    traffic = [];
                    try {
                        // split the data return into lines and parse them
                        tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                        jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                            line = line.split(/\t/);
                            date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                            traffic.push([
                                date,
                                parseFloat(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                            ]);
                        });
                    } catch (e) {  }
                    options.series[0].data = traffic;
                });
        };

    $.when(getdata()).done(function (resp){
                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
</script>
```

So it is not working except if before the getdata function, I write:

options.series = [{

```
            }];
```

What can I do to make sure I can set the variable inside the function without writing this?

Also, I cannot set this like

```
options.series[0] = {};
```

Comment: Do not use a global variable if you have a promise anyway!

Answer (score 0):

When your code executes

```
options.series[0].data = traffic;
```

the `options` object does not have a `series` property. So `series[0]` is undefined. You should define that property, either when the `options` object is created or before you set it.

```
var options = new Object();
options.series = [];
```

You'll then need to define the `0th` element of that array before you can set its `data` property.

```
options.series[0] = {};
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, so I will have to specify that it is an array then set it with nothing inside then I can use it in a function. Correct?